# non parallel walls

Tags: timber-framing

Well, I am building a freestanding studio in the backyard. In order to fit the space the measurements of the outer walls will be approx. 8' x 14' x 12' x 16'. Again approximate, and close enough for the purposes of my question. the 8 foot, 14 foot and 12 foot are square, the 16 foot angled, running from the 8 foot wall and connecting to the 12 foot wall. The roof is a lean to with the rafters running the from the 8 foot to the 12 foot. How do I place them? Parallel to the 14' run or 16' run on angle? Can't run them the other way. Any ideas? See rough drawing to further explain. Thanks

Comment: Are you saying the shape is roughly a trapezoid like this https://cdn1.byjus.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/maths/2016/08/05103457/Right-Trapezoids.jpg? If so, parallel to the 14' wall I would expect.

Comment: Both parallels are going to give you mental fits. As strange as it sounds, have you considered fanning in from 16" centers on the 12' wall to (thinks with both hands to calculate 2/3 of 16...) 10-1/2" (roughly!) centers? And I don't want to second guess you, but a variable slope roof perpendicular to the 14' would be much easier.

Comment: you should really review your post

Comment: @jsotola -- are you referring to the questioner or me?

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate, sorry ..... the comment was aimed at the OP ..... visible lack of a "rough drawing"  ..... yours is a comment, not post .... lol

Comment: Builders will usually orient & space the rafters to match the minimum solution for the roofing sheets ie best coverage with least cutting...